# How do I tell Django a user is authenticated?

Tags: django

In this Django code I inherited there is a check for `request.user.is_authenticated()`.

How do I set this authenticated attribute for a user, in particular when I am doing a registration through AJAX JSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To log a user in, you should `django.contrib.auth.login` - see the docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#auth-web-requests

Note, though, that you should authenticate the user (i.e. check their credentials) before you do so, with `django.contrib.auth.authenticate` - same docs as above.

This is regardless of whether you're using AJAX or not - this code has to be in a view somewhere that gets called in order for the user to get logged in. Whether that view is called via AJAX or not is irrelevant.

Comment: registration through AJAX JSON, i believed

Comment: Why the down vote? You still have to call this code somewhere, in order to log a user in, whether that view is called via AJAX or not....??

Answer (score 0):

The only user this will return false for is `AnonymousUser`; all other users have it return true via their superclass. Therefore all you need to do is authenticate the user normally.